# How to access the variables inside a function imported from another page in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, frontend

My goal is to send a large string or an obj to another page on clicking a card. I tried sending the string through Link. But it can't be done since it has more than 4000 characters.
So I decided to store the string to a variable inside a function on clicking the card and export the function to the other page. I successfully did it. My question is that:
How can I access the variable inside the imported function on the other page?

I tried **const {variable} = importedFunction()**. But when i console logged the variable, it says undefined.

Page-1

```
export const handleClick =(obj)=> {
  const objVar= obj  
} 


Page-2

import handleClick from '../../NewsWithSidebar/NewsWithSideBar'

function Single() { 

 const {objVar}= handleClick()
 console.log(objVar) /*(but the console is showing undefined)*/
```

);

Comment: Are you passing `obj` param to `handleClick` function?

Comment: yes..if doing it with the obj is not unable, then passing a string is enough...but both are not working in my way

Answer (score 1):

You can only access a variable if it is defined inside the scope you are working in or one of its ancestors.

You **can't** pull in a function from outside those scopes are read variables from inside it.

---

> ```
> const {objVar}= handleClick()
> ```

For this syntax to work, the function has to **return** an object with an `objVar` property that you can destructure.

```js
const handleClick = () => {
  const something = {
    objVar: 1234
  };
  return something;
};

const {
  objVar
} = handleClick()

console.log(objVar);
```

Comment: The console is still showing undefined..Btw..How to destructure it?

Comment: No, it isn't. I turned the code into a live demo. You destructure using the destructuring syntax that you used in your question and that I continued to use in this answer.

Comment: Yeah..It works when I set the value of objVar as 1234 or any other static string.. But Console still shows undefined when setting the value of objVar as the string i received as parameter in the function

Comment: @MuhammedShahid — Your code **doesn't pass any parameters** to the function in the first place!

Comment: yes..I have passed a parameter in my code in Vs code, I didn't paste it here. it goes like <div onClick={() => {handleClick(obj)}}

Comment: Now you aren't capturing the return value from calling `handleClick` at all.

Comment: can you suggest any way to pass the data dynamically to the other page onClick

Comment: To another page? In react? If you're using multiple pages in react then you should be using [a router](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) so you can use a [`<Link>`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/to-string) and pass it through the pathname where you can read it through [the route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props)

Comment: buddy, I already tried it. I could pass a string through the link with a limited number of characters. But when I pass an object through Link, the console shows undefined.

Comment: I think I must use the session storage so that I can store the data temporarily in the session storage and retrieve it by filtering with a key when  I reach the other page.